# Maven Play Framework 1.3.0-RC3 upgrade

Tags: java, hibernate, maven, playframework

I've a Play Framework 1.2.7 project which is managed by Maven. Now I am trying to upgrade to Play Framework version 1.3.0

What am I doing the way, how to properly upgrade from Play framework 1.2 to 1.3?

### Maven play plugin in the current pom.xml

```
<parent>
    <groupId>com.google.code.maven-play-plugin</groupId>
    <artifactId>play-app-default-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-beta7</version>
</parent>
```

### Changed play plugin to

```
<parent>
    <groupId>com.google.code.maven-play-plugin</groupId>
    <artifactId>play13-app-default-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-beta7</version>
</parent>
```

### Maven --version

```
Apache Maven 3.2.3 (33f8c3e1027c3ddde99d3cdebad2656a31e8fdf4; 2014-08-12T02:58:10+06:00)
Maven home: /usr/local/Cellar/maven/3.2.3/libexec
Java version: 1.7.0_71, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_71.jdk/Contents/Home/jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "mac os x", version: "10.10.1", arch: "x86_64", family: "mac"
```

### mvn package clean and mvn install output

```
[INFO] --- maven-enforcer-plugin:1.0:enforce (enforce-maven) @ gui ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- play-maven-plugin:1.0.0-beta7:initialize (default-initialize) @ gui ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.7:resources (default-resources) @ gui ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 6 resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ gui ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 38 source files to /Users/sultan/project/gui/target/classes
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] /Users/sultan/project/gui/app/models/Dataset.java:[7,36] package javax.validation.constraints does not exist
[ERROR] /Users/sultan/project/gui/app/models/AbstractInstance.java:[14,36] package javax.validation.constraints does not exist
[ERROR] /Users/sultan/project/gui/app/models/User.java:[10,36] package javax.validation.constraints does not exist
[ERROR] /Users/sultan/project/gui/app/models/Experiment.java:[19,36] package javax.validation.constraints does not exist
[ERROR] /Users/sultan/project/gui/app/models/AccessGroup.java:[7,36] package javax.validation.constraints does not exist
[INFO] 27 errors 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 02:16 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2015-01-15T14:45:00+06:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 26M/119M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) on project gui: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:

[ERROR] /Users/sultan/project/gui/app/models/AbstractInstance.java:[29,6] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class NotNull
[ERROR] location: class models.AbstractInstance
[ERROR] /Users/sultan/project/gui/app/models/User.java:[40,6] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class NotNull
[ERROR] location: class models.User
[ERROR] /Users/sultan/project/gui/app/models/Experiment.java:[30,6] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class NotNull
[ERROR] location: class models.Experiment
[ERROR] /Users/sultan/project/gui/app/models/Experiment.java:[49,6] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class NotNull
[ERROR] location: class models.Experiment
[ERROR] symbol:   class ConstraintViolationException
[ERROR] location: class controllers.ExperimentController
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

I have tried to upgrade Hibernate but it didn't help

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have marked any dependency as a runtime dependency. Try changing the scope to compile.

Comment: they are not marked as runtime dependencies, we can see the most errors related to Hibernate annotations

Comment: Have you tried running with -X to see if the more verbose output gives you more information? The compiler complains becaus ethe classes cannot be resolved. That typically means that something in the Maven config keep the jars with these classes from being added into the compile class path. You can also try dependency:tree to see if the resulting dependcey tree contains the jar with the missing classes.

Comment: yes it is there in tree `javax.validation:validation-api:jar:1.0.0.GA:compile`

Answer (score 0):

`play13-app-default-parent:1.0.0-beta7` depends on play `1.3.0-RC1`. This version of Play! does not contain `validation-api` in it's dependencies, it was added in `1.3.0-RC2` but neither `1.3.0-RC2` nor `1.3.0-RC3` were deployed to Maven central. `1.3.0` was deployed.
Next version of `play13-app-default-parent` will depend on `1.3.0`.
For now you have to add one project property to switch to `1.3.0`:

```
<properties>
    ...
    <play.version>1.3.0</play.version>
</properties>
```